# How to make the following screen on iOS, which UI elements i need to use where?

Tags: ios

Screen contains 3 dynamic lists. Screen should be scrollable, but i know the total amount of the items in every list before displaying the UI (no need in infinite scroll)

```
Cats
 Cat1 image + Cat1 label
 ... 
 CatN image + CatN label
 Button: ADD NEW CAT >

Dogs
 Textarea or button with description1
 ...
 Textarea or button with descriptionN
(No button to add a new dog)

Promocode
 Textarea or button with promo1
 ...
 Textarea or button with promoN
 (Button "+" ) + editText to input promo
```

Every 3 sections has unique differences in design.
Should i use 3 different collectionviews on this screen? should i add scrollview as the root? Please advice

Comment: This questions feels like it would better fit in the UX exchange rather than stackoverflow.

Comment: It is about basic components to be used only. I am not allowed to change the UI/UX :(

Comment: What about a tableview/collection view with 3 sections and custom cells?

Comment: i am not an expert in ios, so my main guess right now is 
1) maybe i can split it all by 3 cells and use different cell identifiers
2) 3 different collectionviews but the question here will the usual scroll view as a root will be enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already answered in the comment but i'm gonna write down something a bit more complete here.

If you already have all the information you need (which should always be the case) before loading your view, then we're all set.

I suggest a scrollview either of `tableview` type or `collectionview` type.

You'd have 3 sections in them?

Since you need different cells (apparently) in each section, you could have 3 different custom cells.

When building your table/collectionview, you would check for the current section

```
(if tableview.section == 0) //(or 1 or 2)
```

and load the required cell at that point. Then fill it with relevant information.

To add your button at the end of each section you could have another custom cell that would only load if you're section X and at the last index. That's another inner `if`

```
//Inside every section code, you'd check if its the last element of the array.
if (indexPath.row == [yourArray count]-1)
```

And obviously in your "numberOfRowsInSection" you'd need to add that extra row :

```
 if (section == 0){
    return [yourArray count]+1;
}else if (section == 1){
  //... repeat for your section1 array
}
```

So you'd need 3 arrays, one for section 0, one for section 1 and one for section 2. The first one would hold all your cat objects, the second one your dogs, and so on.

Now that will work and maybe look good but I'm not an ios expert either.

Comment: When you are saying "3 sections" do you mean
"set collectionview.items to 3?

The rest will be to put all elements for the section in it f.e. top label + (button + text) + "ADD NEW CAT >" and hide label and ADD button in regular cells draw?

Comment: a section is a section, its a property of the collectionview (or tableview)  by itself. I mean that you set the number of sections of the view to 3. NOT the number of items. The number of items (which is 18 for example) has to be set for each section. That's my last bit of code in the answer.

Comment: I would also make a total of 6 customs cells which I would load depending on where we are in the tableview/collectionview.
You'd have 6 cases, section 0 with all items, section 0 last item, section 1 all times, section 1 last item, section 2 all items, section 2 last item.

Comment: How can i add section in the xcode? That is probably my main problem right now =) in Objective-C i can see numberOfItemsInSection or section in methods which i have to override

Comment: find a classic tableview/collection view tutorial with customs cells and another with sections. Anything on the internet can help you from there, I can't re-type a whole guide here ;)
Look at this for example : 
http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-index-list-uitableview/

and this https://owenandrewsblog.wordpress.com/2012/01/29/uitableview-sections-tutorial/

You need to try them all and then you'll have learned how to use tableview. From there, you can make your own !